# Reading remote private transactional queue

Tags: c#, msmq, windows-server-2008-r2

Is it possible at all to read remote transactional private queues on a windows server 2008R2 from another machine ?

I am trying to read messages from a local transactional private queue and it works fine but when i try to read from a remote transactional queue which is part of a windows Server 2008R2 . I have been looking for any information on the web but only found the following [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms699854%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

I would be glad if some one can suggest any thing that has to be changed in order to read remote transactional private queue ?

Comment: Remote queue should public to be accessible outside, obviously. Otherwise naming it 'private' makes no sense at all. Does it?

Comment: i think private queues are only accessable fom that machine, why do you want to do this?

Comment: @LukeMcGregor  I want to do this for a clustered solution of MSMQ.

Comment: Did you try to create and try to access a public queue? Should work for you.

Comment: @abatishchev No, Public and Private can be accessed from anywhere. This is a huge misunderstanding that never seems to go away. The only difference between Public and Private is whether they are published in Active Directory or not. It's exactly like having your phone number published in a telephone directory - someone can call you regardless of whether you are in the book or not.

Comment: @Macnique Remote transactional reading uses RPC and requires several layers of security to be set correctly. Start here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2010/03/24/understanding-how-msmq-security-blocks-rpc-traffic.aspx